# mPDF - Any way to edit the crop marks?

Tags: php, mpdf

Is there a way to edit the crop marks design? this is what I'm trying to achieve:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3ZuZ.png)

This is my Code:

```
function generate_pdf($content, $pdf_width, $pdf_height, $file_name, $bleed = true) {
    $bleed_size = 3; //5mm either side of the doc
    $width      = ($bleed ? $pdf_width + $bleed_size : $pdf_width); //if bleed - increase by 10mm
    $height     = ($bleed ? $pdf_height + $bleed_size : $pdf_height); //if bleed - increase by 10mm
    
    $mpdf       = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
        'mode'          => '',
        'format'        => [$width, $height],
        'img_dpi'       => 300,
        'cropMarkLength' => 3,
        'cropMarkMargin' => 10,

    ]);
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    
    if($bleed) {
        $mpdf->cropMarkMargin = 10;
        $mpdf->cropMarkLength = 3;
        $content = add_bleed($content, $pdf_width, $pdf_height);
    }
    
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
    $mpdf->Output($file_name, 'F');
}


function add_bleed($content, $width, $height) {
    $b_width = $width - 3;
    $b_height = $height - 3;
    $bleed = '
<style>
    @page {
        size: '.$b_width.'mm '.$b_height.'mm;
        marks: crop;
        background-image:url(print_back.png);
        background-size:cover;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:center center;
    }
</style>
';
    return $bleed.$content;
}
```

And this is the current result But I'd like it to be like the first image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y7rw.png)